# R override certain columns for child articles in Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, overwrite

I have a data frame with line-by-line product data, including child articles. Now I would like to transfer certain values (columns) from the father to all children.

Example:

```
 data.frame(sku = c("V1000837", "V1000837-001", "V1000837-002", "01549831"),
           height = c(10, 12, NA, 50),
           width = c(15, NA, 15, 150),
           color = c("red", "blue", "green", "black"),
           power = c("12W", NA, NA, "130W"))

    sku height width color power
V1000837     10    15   red   12W
V1000837-001 12    NA  blue  <NA>
V1000837-002 NA    15 green  <NA>
01549831     50   150 black  130W
```

Now I would like to take over values of a column of the parent article (starts with V and does not end with "-\d{3}") to all children (starts with V and end with "-\d{3}").

I just want to take over the values of the column "**power**" and "**width**" from the father for the associated children.

The result should look like this:

```
sku height width color power
V1000837     10    15   red  12W
V1000837-001 12    15  blue  12W
V1000837-002 NA    15 green  12W
01549831     50   150 black  130W
```

Unfortunately, I have no approach.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the data on `"-"` into different columns. Group by the parent (father) value and `fill` `power` and `width` columns. You can `unite` the values again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(sku, c('father', 'child'), sep = '-', fill = 'right') %>%
  group_by(father) %>%
  fill(power, width, .direction = 'updown') %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unite(sku, father, child, na.rm = TRUE, sep = '-')

#  sku          height width color power
#  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1 V1000837         10    15 red   12W  
#2 V1000837-001     12    15 blue  12W  
#3 V1000837-002     NA    15 green 12W  
#4 01549831         50   150 black 130W
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the quick answer.
What do I have to adjust so that not only NA values but also empty strings are replaced?

Comment: Replace empty strings to `NA`. Something like `...%>% mutate(across(c(height, weight), ~replace(., . == '', NA))) %>%...`